# carrot2 Workbench and filter Query fq

Tags: solr, workbench, carrot2

i need to add [clusteringComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent) from solr to my application. For tuning the clusteringComponent i use the Carrot2 workbench, which is very useful to find out what ar the right parameters.
The point is: i only like to analyse / cluster new data, which is added at the past 24 hours to the solr/lucene index. For that usually i use an timestemp filed on querytime, like:

```
....&fq=timestemp:[NOW-24HOUR TO NOW]
```

The question is: is there a way to add this filter query to the carrot2 workbench as an search parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked that currently there is no way to pass extra Solr parameters from the production releases of Carrot2 Workbench. I've already [added such a feature](http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-943), it is available in [development builds of Carrot2 Workbench](http://download.carrot2.org/head/).

If you'd like to stick with production releases of Carrot2, a possible workaround may be configuring the extra fq parameter directly in your Solr request handler.

Comment: >"extra fq parameter directly in your Solr request handler." that is an good idea/workaround. I did it now. :-) Btw: i have downloaded workbench 3.7.0-last snapshot but could not found an field for adding those parameters. One more question: is it possible to save the tuned attributes at an Solr compatible XML form (to simply import this to solrconfig.xml)  or export as URL Parameter list? - Thank you.

Comment: There's no extra field -- you can now add extra parameters directly in the Solr Service URL text box, e.g.: http://localhost:8983/solr/select?fq=timestemp:[NOW-24HOUR TO NOW].

Comment: See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent#Tuning_Carrot2_clustering) for an XSLT transform you can use to convert attributes in Carrot2 format to the solrconfig.xml format.

Comment: btw... it seems to be important to write the parameter URL encoded, like: `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?fq=timestemp:[NOW-24HOUR%20TO%20NOW]` (as you can see: `%20`instead of space)